# PHP HTML DOM PARSER-span class id

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using PHP and using the HTML DOM PARSER...And trying to retrieve..."STORE FRONT 9TERF"
How do I accomplish this?

```
<span class "id="yui_3_18_1_1_1437448946157_8369">"STORE FRONT 9TERF"<span class="value-suffix"></span></span>


include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file("URL");

 foreach($html->find('span [id=yui_3_18_1_1_1437448000304_8422]') as $data){
    echo "Info: ";    echo $data->innertext; 

   }
//echo $html->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$html->find('span#yui_3_18_1_1_1437448000304_8422')
```

More [examples](https://github.com/samacs/simple_html_dom/blob/master/example/example_basic_selector.php)